# Wildcards generic in Kotlin for variable

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to declare generic wildcards in Kotlin like this code in Java:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> b = a;
```

Comment: This is covered in the Kotlin documentation. Short answer: Kotlin doesn't have wildcards, it uses the concepts of declaration-site variance and type projections instead. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The equivalent in Kotlin would be like this:

```
val a = ArrayList<Int>()
val b: ArrayList<out Number> = a
```

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin doesn't have wildcards, it uses the concepts of declaration-site variance and type projections instead.

Please check the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), covers pretty extensively.

Kotlin provides so called star-projection

```
val a = ArrayList<Int>()
val b: ArrayList<out Number> = a
```